# Can not download a song with Download Manager in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am working with Download Manager in one of my Android projects. Here is my code for downloading a song from URL.

```
private void DownloadTask(String downloadUrl){

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
    request.setDescription("Testando");
    request.setTitle("Download");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.mp3");

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

    showDownloadProgressDialog("Downloading", DownloadManagerActivity.this);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {

                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                    dismissDialog();
                }


                final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                    }
                });

                Log.d("Status", statusMessage(cursor));
                cursor.close();
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

It is working fine with downloading songs with most URLs, but it is not working with following URL
http://pleer.com/browser-extension/files/5353392s90O.mp3

I have tried to download the same song with AsyncTask and it works like a charm. Here is the code for it

```
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();


            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+MusicConstants.FOLDERNAME+"/"+downloadingSongName+".mp3");
            Log.e("File Saved at==>",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+MusicConstants.FOLDERNAME+"/"+downloadingSongName+".mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            song.setSongDownloadedPath(ExternalStorage.getSdCardPath()+MusicConstants.FOLDERNAME+"/"+downloadingSongName+".mp3");
            Log.e("File Saved at==>",ExternalStorage.getSdCardPath()+MusicConstants.FOLDERNAME+"/"+downloadingSongName);
            long success=db.addSongInDatabase(song);

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

what should be the problem with Download Manager? is it the problem with URLs? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what was the problem? faced the same in 2022 - can download jpeg, but no mp3

Answer (score 0):

Download manager cause problems with some complicated Urls just give a try with adding these three lines

```
      downloadUrl = downloadUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
      downloadUrl = downloadUrl.replace("[", "%5B");
      downloadUrl = downloadUrl.replace("]", "%5D");
```

above

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
```

in your source code